# "in order to", "as to", or just "to"

Tags: grammar

I looked up some other posts related to this, but I'm still not 100% clear. In the following examples, are these all grammatically correct, and therefore a matter of style? I want to use the most simple "to" version, but fear it might not be correct. Thanks!

He set the bag down **to** better grip the railing.

He set the bag down **in order to** better grip the railing.

He set the bag down **as to** better grip the railing.

Comment: (1) and (2) are possible, (3) should be 'so as to'.

Comment: I've read elsewhere that "in order to" is considered obsolete. I often want to use that phrase, so can anyone comment on this?

Comment: @KateBunting really? I actually used that wrong then in another sentence. Do you have more info on this? Thanks!!!

Comment: @Jan This is the first time I've heard anybody mention a problem with *in order to*. As far as I know, it's perfectly legitimate. I find the statement that it's considered obsolete to be completely out of the blue. Do you have a reference for this?

Comment: Are you asking about 'so as to' or @Jan 's 'in order to'? https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/in_order_to calls it redundant rather than obsolete. It does seem a bit wordy in such a simple sentence, but could provide clarity in a more complex one.

Comment: @romebot See Merriam-Webster's [entry](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/so%20as%20to#h2) for *so as to*.

Comment: @JasonBassford, I should probably say redundant instead of obsolete; the Wiktionary (linked by Kate in the comment above) says exactly what I wanted to say. Anyway, "in order to" can emphasize  the intention...

Comment: thanks all! great feedback.